# Using Scrapy to Extract Wikipedia Links

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am learning about scrapy and am trying to use it to scrape the below Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_the_2020s

I would like to scrape each country and the hyperlink attached to that country and below is my code so far:

```
import scrapy


class CountrypopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'countryPop'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_the_2020s']

    def parse(self, response):
        countries = response.xpath('//table//b//@title').extract()

        for country in countries:

            country_url = response.xpath('//table//b[contains(@href, 'Afghanistan')]').extract()

            yield {'countries': country}
```

What it currently does is get all the countries from the main table and then I want it to loop through each of these countries, using the country name to get the url. I am having trouble though finding a way of using the country name to find the url, my latest attempt was using contains().

Any other comments on my scraping code would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know scrapy well enough to answer this, but you can directly reference `href` the way you referenced title. Look at [this part of the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) for something quite similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**Approach 1**

```
import scrapy

class CountrypopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'countryPop'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_the_2020s']


    def parse(self, response):
        coutries=200
        cnames=['Australia','Bhutan']
        noduplicateset= set()
        for cname in cnames:
            for title in response.xpath('//table[1]//a[contains(@title,'+cname+')]'):
                if cname not in noduplicateset:
                    yield {cname:'https://en.wikipedia.org'+title.css('a').get().split("\"")[1]}
                noduplicateset.add(cname)
```

**Approach 2**

```
import scrapy

class CountrypopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
    name = 'countryPop'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_the_2020s']


    def parse(self, response):
        coutries=200
        cnames=['Australia','Bhutan']
        for i in range(5,coutries):
            for title in response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i+2)+']/td[1]/b/a'):
                name=title.css('a ::text').get()
                if name in cnames:
                    yield {name:'https://en.wikipedia.org'+title.css('a').get().split("\"")[1]}
```

If you output to json file, it will look like this
[image: json file]